# Cloudflare cipher selection based on AES-NI support

Tags: tls, nginx, cloudflare

How does Cloudflare selects AES ciphers on devices with AES acceleration and ChaCha on devices without it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the TLS handshake the client sends the ciphers it supports in the order of preference. This way a client can signal that it would prefer ChaCha instead of AES ciphers since ChaCha is less resource intensive than AES when implemented in software only. The server can adhere to the clients preference when choosing the cipher and thus select ChaCha instead of AES.

Comment: So I don't need to specify `ssl_ciphers` directive in nginx configuration ? Client will send prefered ciphers and server will respect that order ?

Comment: @user3448600: only if `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers` is off. Otherwise the server will enforce its cipher order. But I think Cloudflare is doing the selection more intelligent than you could do with nginx alone. But still it is based on the cipher order sent by the client.